# Partial class template specialization with maps

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, iterator, partial-specialization

I'm a new C++ programmer, I learned Java and ANSI C a time ago and decided to give it a shot.

Well, I love C++, but I didn't like how the iterators work:

In java, you could make a whole container private and implement a getter function to it's iterator, and the iterator has a method `hasNext()` that returns a boolean depending on if it has reached the end of the container.

The only way I found to do something similar on C++ is writing 2 getters, `iteratorBegin()` and `iteratorEnd()`, that returned an interator corresponding to the first and last positions, incrementing the iterator returned by `iteratorBegin()` and comparing it with `iteratorEnd()`, allowed me to iterate over the container until the final position had been reached

But, I want to use only ONE getter method, and I thought: "Let's make my own iterator class"

So far so good, I've done it successfully with sets and lists, but I can't seem to make it with maps, here's the code that's troubling me: (the class is defined in a separate .h, this is called customIterator.cpp)

```
template<typename T, typename D>
const D& custIterator<T,D>::next()
{
    const D& obj = (*it);
    if(hasNext())
    {
        it++;
    }
    return obj;
}

//the above works fine

template<typename T, typename D>
const D& custIterator<map<T,D>,D>::next() //error in this line
{
    D& obj = (*it).second; 
    if(hasNext())
    {
        it++;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

when compiling the specialized method, it says: error: ‘map’ was not declared in this scope
even though I added `#include <map>` on top of the file

I'm using *gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)* with codeblocks

Please, I need some assistance.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: using std::map under your include map.  Or qualifying the map as in custIterator< std::map< T, D>  ... might do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the standard containers are inside the namespace std, you should qualify it thus

```
std::map<T,D>
```

In general I would recommend not trying to carry over Java idioms to C++ since each language has its own idioms and mixing them will confuse other programmers (just as I think that  `#define BEGIN {` isn't the best idea ever).

What you're trying to do is known as *ranges* and is considered by some to be a better solution than C++ iterators but until it makes its way into the language I think it's harmful for each developer to invent their own ranges.

[Further reading](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1407357) or [tl;dr slides](http://www.slideshare.net/rawwell/iteratorsmustgo) (there's a video to go with this which I can't find at the moment).

Comment: +1 "not trying to carry over Java idioms to C++ since each language has its own idioms" - Usually the idioms are there for good reasons.

Comment: What a shameful mistake, thanks a lot, it worked

Now, it seems that I have to read again my manual on template specialization, as I'm having other difficulties compiling the code.

Thanks for your help